# onclick calling a function showing error : "return is a keyword"

Tags: javascript

I am trying to open a popup with the given address on click of the linkbutton and it shows me error for return is a keyword and identifier is expected ...i am using asp.net

```
 <asp:LinkButton ID="CommentAction" href='<%# "CommentAction.aspx?ID="+Td1.InnerText%>' onclick="return popitup(this.href)" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" runat="server" >
```

Comment: Change `onclick="return popitup(this.href)"` to `onclick="popitup(this.href)"`

Comment: chnage  to onclick="popitup(this.href); return false;"

Comment: You can change to onclick="popitup(this.href)" and put return inside function.

Comment: this same thing worked when i used <a> tag can anybody explain me why is it like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your pageload add in your page load function if you are using c# like me:

```
databind();
```

if you have not done that there will be no data and hence you will be getting null value